# Issue getting tinyMCE spellchecker plugin to work with IE6

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-6, tinymce, spell-checking

Let me start off by saying I realize that this is a long shot. I've spent about 7 hours on this already making zero progress or finding any leads. Debugging in IE6 is no fun.

I have implemented the tineMCE editor spellcheck pluging using ASP.NET, following instructions on this page: http://www.kelvinluck.com/2009/01/using-spell-checker-for-tinymce-with-net-on-iis/

**Everything works in IE8, Firefox, Chrome, etc**

IE6, however, hangs up once the spell check button is pressed (only when spelling errors are found).

[image: it does this forever...]
At this point it just spins the ajax indicator forever.

I have used fiddler to compare the ajax calls with the ie8 version which is working great. There is no difference in the POST or the response. It generates the response with all the bad words identified in both versions.

I have used debugBar to check for errors, what I get is "Invalid Argument", but the line number is always different and in the high millions, typically, which is very weird (this might be because I'm using IE Tester).

I realize this is the kind of question nobody likes, but I'm pretty much out of options, and I need to get this to work in IE6, as this is what our client regretfully uses. I'd be very interested in hearing about some potential debugging methods for IE6 or details regarding tinyMCE's spellchecker plugin.

Comment: Have you looked @ the IIS logs for the website to see if there is anything there?  The reason I ask is because a guy had an issue w/ IE6 @ http://www.esscotti.com/resources/articles/41-general/104-tinymce-not-working-in-ie6-solved

Comment: Also, you mention that you are using IETester.  Have you tried and gotten similar results in a native environment?  I often find nuances with tools that emulate older versions of IE.

Comment: @Ben Yes, I have tested this with a real version of IE6 and had the same results.

Comment: @Ben That's a very good idea. I don't have access to them directly, but this is worth contacting IT about :)

Comment: Other than that, my advice would be to search the web and post on their official forum.  I found a great deal of people having issues with IE6 in Google.

Comment: Yikes.  IE6 is virtually Steam Punk these days.  You'd be better off with a clay tablet and pointy stick.  My guess is that IE6 is erring out some time after the AJAX return.  Modify the MCE code by putting alert() calls at strategic points and see where it's failing.

Comment: I'll suggest the clay tablet/pointy stick option to our client, but with what we're charging them, it's not likely to go over well.

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=22185) is much more reliable than IETester. Here's some tips to work with it:

- If you get an error alert, view source and copy it to a text editor. Find the line number and look before and after it for a syntax errror, such as a hanging comma, missing semicolon, or missing parentheses.
- To prevent breaking on an error, unset the Break on Error toggle button or press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+E</kbd>.
- If you want execution to pause at that breakpoint only when a certain condition is true, then set a condition for that breakpoint. To set a breakpoint Condition, right-click on the breakpoint, select the Condition... option, enter the condition and click OK

Use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for troubleshooting network response issues, and the [JScript Error Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a3syxc5) to help identify the specific error message.